# JMenubar error?

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu();
    JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("aaaa");
    fileMenu.add(item1);
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Pretty simple code. It should show a JMenuBar with a JMenuItem labelled "aaaa" but nothing shows as you can see in the picture below.

I'm using Java Update 24 with JDK 24 on Windows 7 64bit

http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/3457/31137617.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is there, but you can't see it because you didn't give the JfileMenu a name.

```
JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
```

[image]

Comment: thanks garcon that was a quiet dumb error. Anyways thanks. By "accepting", you mean t-upping it?

Comment: No, keep looking, you'll see how to do it.  You'll see the check box next to the answer that you will need to check.  This says that you've "accepted" the answer.

Comment: @I82Much: Fro reference, you can capture just a single window using ⌘-⌥-4 followed by space, as described [here](http://guides.macrumors.com/Taking_Screenshots_in_Mac_OS_X).

Comment: Thanks I am aware of that but it didn't seem to be working correctly with the popup.  Normally that's what I do, as it gives a beautiful drop shadow effect.